# 14.04 - How to enable both Right click and Multi-Touch in ElanTech touchpad?

Tags: 14.04, multi-touch

I have a Lenovo Z50-70 with elantech touchpad and Ubuntu does not detect multi-touch gestures (E.g. two finger scroll).

If I act according to [here](http://www.evilcodingmonkey.com/2014/01/23/ubuntu-activate-multi-touch-on-elantech/) I will have multi-touch gestures but right-click button does not work. Also if I act according to [here](https://superuser.com/questions/619582/right-elantech-touchpad-button-not-working-in-linux) I will have right-click but no multitouch. How can I have them both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by installing Debian Testing version.
Debian Jessie (Testing) includes Linux kernel 3.16 while Ubuntu 14.04 has 3.13. I think this caused to fix the problem: Now I have both right-click and two-finger scroll out-of-the-box right after installation!

Comment: So the solution is to upgrade the kernel? If so, you should make that clearer in your answer. It is possible to install the mainline kernel (at the user's own risk) in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I adjusted the touchpad on my Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    # This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
    # enabled by default. See the following link for details:
    # http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

    Option "FingerLow"              "46"
    Option "FingerHigh"             "46"
    Option "ClickFinger1"           "1"
    Option "ClickFinger2"           "2"
    Option "ClickFinger3"           "3"
    Option "TapButton1"             "1"
    Option "TapButton2"             "3"
    Option "TapButton3"             "2"
    Option "AreaBottomEdge"         "85%"
    Option "SoftButtonAreas"        "60% 0 85% 0 40% 60% 85% 0" # Btn2 LRTB - Btn3 LRTB
    Option "EmulateMidButtonTime"   "75"
EndSection
```

Maybe this helps.

(source: http://memobadz.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/lenovo-yoga-pro-2-on-ubuntu/ )

Comment: Thanks. Does it work with 'Elantech' touchpad too?

Comment: You would have to adapt it. What files do you have in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d? Please look at the source link I posted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for others searching for answer...
I got it with two fingers touching the pad and clicking the left button in the same time. (discovered accidentaly after spending hours with typing commands)